# I want my web API work with both HTTP and HTTPS requests

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have rest web API which is used internally, as well as externally by a third party, and it is called through URL.

I want it to work with both HTTP and HTTPS requests. It's working fine with HTTP requests, but with HTTPS requests it showing a error. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure an SSL certificate on the web server. If you are using IIS here's a tutorial on how this could be done: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Once you install a certificate your API will be accessible on HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks :)....Is it also required for third party client to install certificates for https request????Because without this API gives SSl certificate error untrusted like this....Any way to access a Rest API with HTTPS without installing SSl certificates on third party server???

Comment: No, HTTPS means SSL. In order to use it you need to install a certificate. If you want this certificate to be trusted you will have to purchase a certificate from a trusted authority. Alternatively you could disable certificate validation on the client but this is not recommended for production environments, only for testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot,you help me in this confusion.I have last question if I purchase SSL certificate and host my Web API on it and use transport security in it.Now if third party call my Api Are they need certificates or not?????If yes i know the solution if not then how to implement on thisrd party end or i have to change in my rest web API???

Comment: No, the clients do not need to know anything about the certificate.

Comment: Great, there won't be any problems for them. They do not need any SSL. This is something that you need to configure on your server if you want your API to be accessible through HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks :)....Any idea how to configure on my side because i tried many things but fail....My Api in C#.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.with https request how to manage?